# Linq TypeScript Ternary Operator - is it possible to re-use the condition as the first expression without duplicating code?

Tags: typescript, linq

My question is pretty simple and I've searched through StackOverflow, StackExchange + some other sites trying to find an answer, but have come up a little short.

It's regarding a Linq ternary expression, i.e.

```
Condition ? Expression1 : Expression2;
```

Essentially, can I re-use the `Condition` of a Linq ternary expression as the first returned `Expression`? Is this possible?

The reason for me wanting to do this is I have a very long Linq ternary expression which spans 3 lines in-code and extends over 183 characters. The main reason it is so long is because of some strings & variable names.

**An abridged version of my code is as follows:**

```
var x = array.find(x => x.key == "EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME") ? array.find(x => x.key == "EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME") : null;
```

Or

```
var x = array.find(x => x.key == "EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME") ? array.find(x => x.key == "EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME").value : null;
```

A couple of solution's I've considered are:

- Store the `array.find(x => x.key == "EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME")` section in a variable to reference later
- Use an `If` statement

I have decided against both of these as they add additional overhead in terms of how much physical code is on the page.

I guess what it boils down to is, does something like this exist? (Where `this` is the initial condition)

```
var x = array.find(x => x.key == "EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME") ? this : null;
```

It may also be used in this context where I'm after a specific value stored in the object:

```
var x = array.find(x => x.key == "EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME") ? this.value : null;
```

This is my first time asking a question though I've answered quite a few questions, so please feel free to give constructive feedback or point me in the direction of documentation to read!

Comment: `var x = array.find(x => x.key == "EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME") || null;`

Comment: Ah that's a neat trick! I've updated my question a little as there's another reason I'm asking - and this comment doesn't quite solve it. I'd appreciate it if you'd have a read! Thanks! :)

Comment: You can use optional chaining: `var x = array.find(x => x.key == "EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME")?.value || null;`

Comment: Amazing! Thankyou! If you want to post that as an answer I'd be more than happy to mark it as the accepted answer! For me I'm using Typescript 3.0.1 and this was introduced in TS 3.7, but irrespective it will work great once I update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use optional chaining and the `||` operator for this:

```
 var x = array.find(x => x.key == "EXAMPLE_KEY_NAME")?.value || null;
```